# Two levels of itemization with the 'intext' option

Tags: context, itemize, context-mkiv

In ConTeXt, how can I get the **output** given by the following code, but **using the itemize
environment**?

```
\starttext
\quad---~Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab
illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,
explicabo.\par
\quad---~Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab
illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,
explicabo.\par
\quad\quad~---~Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa,
quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
sunt, explicabo.\par
\quad\quad~---~Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa,
quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
sunt, explicabo.\par
\quad---~Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab
illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,
explicabo.
\stoptext
```

I have tried this, but without success (it works only when there is one
level of itemization):

```
\definesymbol[emdashone][\quad---~]
\definesymbol[emdashtwo][\quad\quad~---~]
\setupitemize[1][packed, fit, intext][symbol=emdashone]
\setupitemize[2][packed, fit, intext][symbol=emdashtwo]
\starttext
\startitemize
    \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab
illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,
explicabo.
    \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab
illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,
explicabo.
    \startitemize
        \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa,
quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
sunt, explicabo.
        \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa,
quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
sunt, explicabo.
    \stopitemize
    \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab
illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,
explicabo.
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to explicitly set the width of each symbol, and align the symbol to the right. Visually, this is give the output that you want. For example:

```
\definesymbol[emdash][---]
\setupitemize[1][packed, intext][symbol=emdash, width=2em, itemalign=left, distance=0.5ex]
\setupitemize[2][packed, intext][symbol=emdash, width=3em, itemalign=left, distance=0.5ex]
```

Unfortunately, the intuitive `\setupitemize[1,2][...][...=...]` does not work.

Comment: Thanks so much Aditya, that's exactly what I was looking for.
You've just forgotten to add the distance of _one space_ to the width of the 2nd level so that the 2nd level symbols start at the beginning of the texts of the 1st level, but that's a detail (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution with the help of Aditya:

```
\definesymbol[emdash][---]
\setupitemize[each][packed, intext][%
    itemalign=left,
    symbol=emdash,
    distance=\spaceamount]
\setupitemize[1][width=2em]
\setupitemize[2][width=\dimexpr 3em + \interwordspace \relax]
\setupitemize[3][width=\dimexpr 4em + 2\interwordspace \relax]
\setupitemize[4][width=\dimexpr 5em + 3\interwordspace \relax]

\starttext
\startitemize
    \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit 
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam 
eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto 
beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
    \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit 
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam 
eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto 
beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
    \startitemize
        \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error 
sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
        \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error 
sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
        \startitemize
            \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus 
error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
            \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus 
error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
            \startitemize
                \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus 
error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
                \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus 
error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem 
aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi 
architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.
            \stopitemize
        \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```